# How to display a binary number on LEDs (Raspberry Pi GPIO) Python

Tags: python, binary, led

I have some LEDs wired to my Pi's GPIO pins and I want to display, lets say an 8 bit binary number, on the LEDs. So if the number is 11110000 then I want the first four LEDs to be on and the last four to be off.

I converted a decimal number to binary and I want to be able to display this binary number using simple LEDs.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably start by converting the binary number into a usable list of values, for deciding which of the 8 LEDs to keep turned on.

```
state = 0b11110000

expanded = []
for x in range(8):
    val = state & 0x01
    state = state >> 1
    expanded.append(val)
expanded = list(reversed(expanded))
print(expanded)    # [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Using `expanded` you can decide which LEDs should remain ON.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out but might be a bit complicated in this approach.
So my number is represented as 0b1000101

```
temp = 0b1000101
binF = temp[2:].zfill(7) #prints 1000101
binF1 = temp[3:].zfill(6) #prints 000101
binF2 = temp[4:].zfill(5) #prints 00101
binF3 = temp[5:].zfill(4) #prints 0101
binF4 = temp[6:].zfill(3) #prints 101
binF5 = temp[7:].zfill(2) #prints 01
binF6 = temp[8:].zfill(1) #prints 1

#Now we want the most significant bit
binFA = binF[1:].zfill(1) #prints 1
binF1A = binF1[1:].zfill(1) #prints 0
binF2A = binF2[1:].zfill(1) #prints 0
binF3A = binF3[1:].zfill(1) #prints 0
binF4A = binF4[1:].zfill(1) #prints 1
binF5A = binF5[1:].zfill(1) #prints 0
binF6A = binF6[1:].zfill(1) #prints 1
```

And from here we can assign the values to certain GPIO pins

```
if binFA == '1':
    GPIO.output(21, 1)
else:
    GPIO.output(21, 0)
```

## Set all GPIO pins as necessary for how many bits there are